# How I can fill space between 2 circle in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-design

[image: illustration]

My circle painter:

```
    CircleWavePainter(this.animationValue) {
//add some property to paint
  wavePaint = Paint()
    ..color = Colors.black.withAlpha(100)
    ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
    ..strokeWidth = 1
    ..isAntiAlias = true;
}
```

My paint to draw 2 circles and need some help to fill the space:

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
//circle 1
canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.height / 2, size.width / 2),
80 * (1.4 - animationValue / 2), wavePaint);
//circle 2    
canvas.drawCircle(Offset(size.height / 2, size.width / 2),
80 * (1.8 - animationValue / 2), wavePaint);
}
```

Comment: How about you fill color at large circle and draw again over small circle on large circle with white color?

Comment: I need the free space to show a little widget in the center of the circle. So the way you say work well but not in this case :(

Comment: As Abdallah said, draw big and small and draw a little widget by using Stack at center of circle.

Comment: [link](https://im.ge/i/2lCXP) as you can see, the icon in the center of circle was blur, when the opacity of the "WaveCircles" change.

Comment: Please check again what I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 'Stack' widget instead of 'Paint', implemented your design.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container(
      height: 400,
      width: 400,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 280,
            height: 280,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Color(0xFF4C4D4F),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 140,
            height: 140,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.access_alarm,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 30,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Color(0xFF5EA2EB),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks you, I'm reach what I want to do <3

Answer (score 1):

you can use stack Widget I didn't reach animations on my course but I can give you a hint

```
Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd,
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30,
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
              'https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image',
            ),
          ), //photo
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 7,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          ), // active or not
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 6,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ), // active circle space
        ],
      )
```